# How to clear MemoryTarget Logs in NLog?

Tags: c#, winforms, nlog

I'm using a Memory Target for logging.

```
<target xsi:type="Memory" name="memLog" layout="${longdate} - ${message}" />
```

This is a log heavy application and eventually the log becomes very large and the application runs out of memory.

Is there any way to reset the `MemoryTarget.Logs` collection? It is a read-only property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MemoryTarget.Logs` property implements `IList`.  Why not just clear it like this:

```
MemoryTarget.Logs.Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks! Since the `Logs` has a private setter, I presumed `Clear()` would not work. I just checked and I was very wrong.

Comment: Yeah, C# doesn't allow you to change the reference for a collection, but does allow you to modify it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

**wageoghe** got me on the right track - thanks! - but you need to clear the logs from the instance, not the class, so:

```
MyTarget.Logs.Clear();
```

or

```
LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<MemoryTarget>("MyTarget").Logs.Clear();
```

or, if you're exposing the Logs `IList<string>` publicly, the consuming code can simply do

```
MyLogger.Logs.Clear();
```